# How to display a message to committer on push to Github?

Tags: git, github, pre-commit-hook

Commiters aren't running pre-commit tests! Much build breakage! I want to ultimately install pre-commit hooks to force basic testing, but for today a mildly chastising message will have to suffice.

Is it possible to display a message to the committer whenever he pushes something to the Github repo?

Edit: I need this to be transparent, without the dev installing or running any scripts (which he will likely not do). Since hooks are not pulled, I'm guessing I need to set something on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CLI git client, see the `.git/hooks` directory under your project's root. There you'll find multiple scripts with filenames ending in ".sample".

Pay attention to the `pre-push.sample` and `pre-commit.sample`. These are just bash scripts that will execute on response to different events.

If you want to enable them, just remove the ".sample" from the name.

For instance, you could enable the `pre-commit` one and replace it's contents by:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Run the tests!!!"
```

You could also use the script to run the tests everytime someone commits.

IMO thought, you should just enforce your project's commit policies better since it would be trivial for you teammates to disable the hooks. (Maybe a mixture of both measures is the sweet spot).

Take a look at [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.html) to see all the available hooks and plenty of info about them.

Comment: Can I do this without the active cooperation of the devs? Hooks afaik are local, and they are unlikely to install anything. If there is a way to make the hooks get pulled along with the repo, that would work brilliantly.